# Read and remove all html/css tags in content file (php)

Tags: php, file, strip-tags

I'm trying to develop a code to read a file and to remove the html and css tags in content, saving the modifications in this same file. Initially, I thought to use the fgetss function. But the function works in only 1/3 of file, and don't show others strings.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) 
    {
        $file = $_FILES["arq"]["name"];
        $content = " ";
        echo $file;
        $pont = fopen($file, "r");

        do {
            $content = $content . " " .fgetss($pont);
        } while(!feof($pont));

        fclose($pont);


        $pont2 = fopen($file, "w");
        fwrite($pont2, $content);

        fclose($pont2);
        echo("fim");
    }
?>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" id="arq" name="arq" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

And after, I developed other way, using strip_tags, but have been occurred the same error:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) 
    {
        $file = $_FILES["arq"]["name"];
        $content = "";
        $pont = fopen($file, "r");

        do {
            $content = $content. " " .fgets($pont);
        } while(!feof($pont));

        $content = strip_tags($content);

        fclose($pont);

        $pont2 = fopen($file, "w");
        fwrite($pont2, $content);

        fclose($pont2);
        echo("fim");
    }
?> 

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" id="arq" name="arq" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: If you're going to read the entire file into a variable, why not just use `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Can you describe the content of the files you are trying to read? Are they complete HTML documents of fragments of text with html tags??

Comment: @rickdenhaan I'm tried now and the same error occurred! any tips are welcome!

Comment: @RamRaider the file has divided by head, css, scripts and body tags.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code to process the uploaded file. Are you sure you're reading the correct file? The path to the actual uploaded file is in `$_FILES['arq']['tmp_name']`. Have you tried reading that file?

Comment: @rickdenhaan  the idea is to remove the html, css and scripts tags in file, not upload. The ways showed here has working, but not 100%. This remove the tags in lasts parts of file. But in begin, the content desappeared.

Comment: Remove tags using standard PHP function strip_tags() - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp